# How to darken the background image of a responsive div on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking for a solution to this exact problem for the last two days. I get certain parts to work but other things stop working... I use bootstrap (only the container class though), and am very new to Javascript, jQuery.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have a div with a background image. Now, I want to darken ONLY the background image onClick, not the text (so it becomes more readable). I want to do this with a second div that has a black background color and 50% opacity, and covers the whole background. The Javascript or jQuery I want to keep to a minimum, so that I only need to put a div with the class "darken" on top of every image that can be toggled on and off by clicking it (default should be off, or invisible).

I'm really lost here. Does it have something to do with the z-index? Or maybe the position?

(also a JSfiddle that works, and kind of does what I want it to, but only in jQuery 1.8.3. I have no idea why; http://jsfiddle.net/5AJ6m/9/)

See my code below:
(JSfiddle with my code and random images for you guys http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/159/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="darken.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!--http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/136/-->
<!--http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/135/-->
    <div id="entry_10-06-2014">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Impressions and other stuff
        </h1>
                <h2>taken from my awesomely weird life
        </h2>
                <h3><em>10th</em> of June, 2014 - <em>Brooklyn</em>, NYC
        </h3>
                <div class="seperator">
                    <img src="Design/Seperator_01.svg">
                </div>
                <p>Random projections have recently emerged as a powerful method for dimensionality reduction. Theoretical results indicate not much. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed mollis magna eu ultricies laoreet? Pellentesque tempus ornare nisi; quis dictum tortor dapibus id. Aliquam malesuada odio vitae ipsum cursusLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="darken"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="entry_11-06-2014">
            <div class="container">
                <h1>Impressions and other stuff
        </h1>
                <h2>taken from my awesomely weird life
        </h2>
                <h3><em>10th</em> of June, 2014 - <em>Brooklyn</em>, NYC
        </h3>
                <div class="seperator">
                    <img src="Design/Seperator_01.svg">
                </div>
                <p>Random projections have recently emerged as a powerful method for dimensionality reduction. Theoretical results indicate not much.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="darken"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandontext-black';
    src: local('BrandonText-Black.otf'), url('/Fonts/BrandonText-Black.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'brandontext-light';
    src: local('BrandonText-Light.otf'), url('/Fonts/BrandonText-Light.otf') format('opentype');
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
}
body {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Black', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 40px #606060;
}
::selection {
    color: white;
    background: #454545;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 81px;
    text-align: center;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Light', sans-serif;
    margin-top: -5px;
    text-align: center;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Light', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.seperator {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.seperator img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
p {
    font-size: 42px;
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Light', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
em {
    font-family: 'BrandonText-Black', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
}
.container {
    padding: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
}
.darken {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
}
#entry_10-06-2014 {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('Images/10-06-2014.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 700px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#entry_11-06-2014 {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('Images/11-06-2014.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 700px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.darken').toggle(
    function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
```

I'm thankful for any help!

Comment: I put it in my question, but here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/159

Comment: Got an awesome answer for your question. Posting in few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do that:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$("body > div").click(function() {
    if($(this).hasClass('darken')) {
       $(this).removeClass('darken');
    }
    else {
       $(this).addClass('darken');
    }
});
});
</script>
```

And

```
<style>
.darken:before {
background: black;
content: "";
opacity: 0.4;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 2;
}
</style>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/167/

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, thanks!
But! Is it possible to removeClass on a second click? That would be awesome!

Comment: Cool. Updated the code. Please mark this as correct answer by clicking on hollow tick above :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Is it possible to have the img NOT darkened before clicking? What I mean is: The .darken class should only be visible after the background is clicked. 

Right now the black with 0.4 opacity is always visible, and added a second time after clicking. 

It should be invisible before clicking, and added only after it is clicked.

Comment: You sure bro? Check out the fiddle it works perfect. I've just copied code from fiddle. check the fiddle. It is working exactly how you say

Comment: Here I edited the opacity of the .darken:before to 0.01 http://jsfiddle.net/N4eCr/173/ Initially it should look like that, and once clicked have a 0.5 opacity. Do you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

This would be my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/gcGEV/), it does the darking only with css

css:

```
.background
{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    color: orange;
    background-image: url('http://www.desktop-bilder.com/images/medium_thumbs/4159-3908.jpg');
}
.dark
{
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.75) 100%), url('http://www.desktop-bilder.com/images/medium_thumbs/4159-3908.jpg');
}
```

html:

```
<div id="background" class="background dark">
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>

<p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.</p>

<p>Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>

<p>Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a,</p>
</div>
<button onclick="doIt();">Test</button>
```

js:

```
function doIt()
{
    $( "#background" ).toggleClass("dark");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Target the .container instead of the .darken div. That way you don't have to change the z-index values you're using.

```
$('.container').toggle(

function () {
```

Now we search the siblings of the .container for .darken and apply the css it

```
   $(this).siblings('.darken')
   .css('background','url(http://www.random.org/analysis/randbitmap-rdo.png)');
},

function () {
   $(this).siblings('.darken').css('background', 'blue');
});
```

I think that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There are backgrounds to other div containers.  which you need to remove. and also wrap the `.darken` container to your elements.

```
$('.darken').toggle(

function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'url(http://www.random.org/analysis/randbitmap-rdo.png)');
    $(this).find('div').each(function (e) {
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
    });
},

function () {
    $(this).css('background', 'blue');
    $(this).find('div').each(function (e) {
        $(this).css('background', '');
    });
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/N4eCr/160/)**

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/N4eCr/162/)